# CapsPageMenu viewDidAppear called on all ViewControllers on swipe

Tags: ios, swift, menu, horizontal-scrolling

I am working with the CapsPageMenu iOS Swift library. I am seeing that on a swipe, the viewDidAppear /viewDidDisappear are being called on all the tabs which are in between. For eg: if I have Tab1,Tab2 and Tab3 and I am currently on Tab1 then when I click on Tab3, I see that Tab2's viewDidAppear/disappear are also being called.. This is most probably since the Tab2 view can be seen scrolling horizontally for a second.. However I need to fetch data from a web service on each of the tabs when they are loaded. Hence this leads to unnecessary network calls.

How can I ensure that the web service calls are only executed for a tab when that tab is actually loaded and not on scrolling past?

Comment: Did u get any solution?

Comment: yeah - I used the CAPSPageMenuDelegate - implemented the didMoveToPage() function in the main controller. This is only called once the tab has been loaded.